# Make list of items scrollable horizontaly

Tags: css, angular

I am facing one issue with my mat chip list from Angular Material.

I have a mat chip list full of mat-chips that i want to add them in one row and if there are more items than the display can show i want the area to be scrollable horizontaly.

Here is the example of my case : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sr6pkk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-input-example.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below css code to styles.scss to make chip-list scrollable horizontaly

```
.mat-chip-list-wrapper {
    /* make all item stay in one row, add !important to override default value: wrap */
    flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
    overflow-x: auto; /* make list scroll when overflow */
}
```

Comment: This is helpfull but is there another way to make this possible as i don't want to make this avaiabile everywhere in my page?